# What constellations does each planet's orbit travel along, from a heliocentric perspective?

Tags: alignment

E.g. What constellations would the sun look to be traveling along when looked at from Mars ?

Comment: This is very similar to your other question (https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/54012). As all planets orbit the Sun close to the ecliptic, they would all seem to travel along the same constellations as seen from the Sun, and the Sun would seem to travel along the same constellations as seen from them, as from the Earth.

Comment: Is there any way to see which constellations line up with the planets not with the ecliptic?

Comment: All planets are close enough to the ecliptic that it doesn’t make a difference. For dwarf planets and candidate dwarf planets, I suggest maybe using a planetarium program and setting the observing location on their surface, or being in orbit around them for those that don’t allow being *on* them.